# How to use Keras LSTM batch_input_size properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I'm using `Keras` framework to build a stacked `LSTM` model as follows:

```py
model.add(layers.LSTM(units=32,
                      batch_input_shape=(1, 100, 64),
                      stateful=True,
                      return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.LSTM(units=32, stateful=True, return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.LSTM(units=32, stateful=True, return_sequences=False))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(train_dataset,
          train_labels,
          epochs=1,
          validation_split = 0.2,
          verbose=1,
          batch_size=1,
          shuffle=False)
```

Knowing that the default `batch_size` for `mode.fit`, `model.predict` and `model.evaluate` is 32, the model forces me to change this default `batch_size` to the same`batch_size` value used in `batch_input_shape (batch_size, time_steps, input_dims)`.

My questions are:

1. What is the difference between passing the `batch_size` into
   `batch_input_shape` or into the `model.fit`?
2. Could I train with `batch_size`, lets say 10, and evaluate on a single batch (rather than
   10 batches) if I passes the `batch_size` into the structure of the
   `LSTM` layer through `batch_input_shape`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `Sequential()` model it is defined to support any batch size. In particular, in `TensorFlow 1.*` the input is a placeholder that has `None` as the first dimension:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, input_shape=(2, )))
print(model.inputs[0].get_shape().as_list()) # [None, 2] <-- supports any batch size
print(model.inputs[0].op.type == 'Placeholder') # True
```

If you use `tf.keras.InputLayer()` you can define a fixed batch size like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer((2,), batch_size=50)) # <-- same as using batch_input_shape
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, input_shape=(2, )))
print(model.inputs[0].get_shape().as_list()) # [50, 2] <-- supports only batch_size==50
print(model.inputs[0].op.type == 'Placeholder') # True
```

The batch size of `model.fit()` method is used to split your data to batches. For example, if you use `InputLayer()` and define a fixed batch size while providing different value of a batch size to the `model.fit()` method you will get `ValueError`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer((2,), batch_size=2)) # <--batch_size==2
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, input_shape=(2, )))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy')
x_train = np.random.normal(size=(10, 2))
y_train = np.array([[0, 1] for _ in range(10)])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=3) # <--batch_size==3
```

This will raise:

`ValueError: The`batch_size`argument value 3 is incompatible with the specified batch size of your Input Layer: 2`

To summarize: If you define a batch size `None` you can pass any number of samples for training or evaluation, even all samples at once without splitting to batches (if the data is too big you will get `OutOfMemoryError`). If you define a fixed batch size you will have to use the same fixed batch size for training and evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

when the lstm layer is in stateful mode, the batch size must be given and cannot be None.
this is because the lstm is stateful and needs to know how to concatenate the hidden states from the t-1 timestep batch to the t timestep batch